Solve for maximum entropy conditional probability
I'm new to max-ent principle and functional derivatives. I have known joint data distribution $p_D(x,y)$ (where $y$ is regarded as the labels) and a latent variable model $(x,y,z)$ with the prior $p(z)$ and the likelihood $p(y \mid x,z)$ specified. I want to find the max-ent probability $p(x \mid z)$ that drives the model to meet the data distribution, i.e.:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(z) p(x \mid z) p(y \mid x,z)\,\mathrm dz = p_D(x,y)\,.\tag{1}
$$
The Lagrangian is:
$$
\begin{multline}
L(p(x \mid z), \lambda_0, \lambda_1) = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x \mid z) \log p(x \mid z)\,\mathrm dx\\
+ \lambda_0 \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x \mid z)\,\mathrm dx - 1\right) + \lambda_1 \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(z) p(x \mid z) p(y \mid x,z)\,\mathrm dz - p_D(x,y)\right)\,.
\end{multline}\tag{2}
$$
Taking derivative and letting it zero:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 + \log p(x \mid z) &= \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 p(z) p(y \mid x,z)\\
p(x \mid z) &= \exp(\lambda_0 - 1 + \lambda_1 p(z) p(y \mid x,z))\,.\\
\end{aligned}\tag{3}
$$
Plugging (3) back to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x \mid z)\,\mathrm dx = 1$ yields:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(C_0 + C_1 f(x))\,\mathrm dx\,,\tag{4}
$$
where $C_0$ and $C_1$ are constants unrelated to $x$, and $f(x) = p(y \mid x,z)$.
The integral (4) diverges, even if $f(x) = 1$ and $C_1 < 0$ all the time. Thus, (3) is not a correct solution.
Therefore, I believe there're some errors in my derivation, most probably in (3). Maybe the Lagrangian in (2) is wrong in the first place.
